# Select folder using browse button in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a requirement where I need to select a folder instead of a file, while clicking a browse button.
The code to select a file, while clicking the browse button will be as below.

```
Case "Browse"
DlgText "path", GetFilePath(,"*.*","C:\","Open sheet")
```

How to change this to select a folder, instead of a file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Case "Browse"
  Dim folderPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select the necessary folder!"
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
            MsgBox "You did not select any folder..."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
  'your existing code...
```

**Edited**:

If you **work in Windows OS**, even if `ERStudio`, which I am not fammiliar to, does not expose such a method, please try the next way, using `VBScript` objects:

```
Case "Browse"
   Dim objSh As Object, objFold As Object, strStartFolder As String, strFolder As String
   
    strStartFolder = "C:\" 'you can use here what starting folder you want
    Set objSh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFold = objSh.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select The necessary Folder", 0, strStartFolder)
    If IsObject(objFold) Then strFolder = objFold.Self.Path
    MsgBox strFolder 'use it where necessary and comment this testing line...
'your existing code...
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but I am getting an error at the below line


"With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)"

Saying, Application and msoFileDialogFolderPicker  not declaired, expecting a valid dtatype.
I am writing this on ERStudio macros. How should I declaire these two?

Comment: @Arun You should state this aspect! In the chosen tags, at least. I never used `ERStudio`. If its `Application` object exposes `FileDialog` try using `4` instead of `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` constant. Maybe it has its own constants...

Comment: @Arun At least, do you work in Windows? If so, I will try editing the answer and placing a different way using a `VBScript` object...

Comment: @Arun Please, use the code placed after **Edited**, and send some feedback.

Comment: Dear FaneDuru , Thank you so much for your help . It worked.  I have been trying to fix this for sometime, at last this worked. Thanks again !!!